# Disable Hyper-V pausing due to low disk space

Tags: windows-server-2012, hyper-v

Is there a way to keep Hyper-V from pausing due to low disk space errors?

I have tried some registry edits but they do not seem to be working.

Is this a policy setting?

Comment: What exactly do you expect Hyper-V to do when it can't process guest VM writes anymore???

Comment: Q: Is there a way to keep Hyper-V from pausing due to low disk space errors? A: Yes. Move the virtual machines to storage with sufficient disk space.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The alternative is disk write failures in the guest OS.  That often causes them to crash.

If you don't want a VM to pause due to low disk space, there are a few things you can do.  First, disable the default "save my VM on host shut down" setting.  This will free up some space.  Second, make your VHD or VHDX files "fixed," rather than "dynamically expanding."  This will mean that all your storage is allocated up front, giving you an idea of what might be required in the future, and ensuring that you simply can't run out of space unexpectedly.

Comment: Keep in mind, the latter option will likely significantly increase the size of your backups. You should account for that when considering your options.